# jQuery "Object doesn't support this property or method" in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, dom

I am using jQuery to add some dynamic content to a website.

I am attempting to create a new DOM element on-demand using the following code:

```
container = $('<div id="myContainer"></div>');
```

This works perfectly in Firefox and Safari, but Internet Explorer is generating an error.  The IE error is: `Object doesn't support this property or method`

I know that jQuery is loading properly, and have tried both the `jQuery` and `$` syntax.

Any ideas as to what might be causing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to add a DOM element, the code needs to be modified a bit:

```
$('body').append('<div id="myContainer"></div>');
// body can be whatever containing element you want to hold myContainer
$('#myContainer').html('whatever you want inside of myContainer');
```

Comment: Still not sure why the original method wasn't working (since the jQuery docs list it), but your method was a perfect alternative. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

I don't know if it can help but I fixed my problem.
Basically IE doesn't want to assign jquery object to an undefined variable.

So what I did is declare this a local variable instead.

Before:

```
function foo() {
  bar = $('#bar');
}
```

After:

```
function foo() {
  var bar = $('#bar');
}
```

Comment: Worked for me.
you might saved me lots of frustration :) thanks

Comment: This is the correct answer. I didn't realize I had gotten sloppy and had `parent = $('#elem')` when I needed `var parent = $('#elem')`. For once I agree with IE. If I'm going to name a variable an existing global variable's name I better be sure to declare it as a new variable first!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. Internet explorer throws this error when you try to modify a global symbol. This is the case not only for reserved words. My example was:

```
function foo() {
    iframe = $("myDiv").append("<iframe></iframe>");
}
```

This solves it:

```
function foo() {
    var iframe = $("myDiv").append("<iframe></iframe>");
}
```

This, too:

```
function foo() {
    myIframe = $("myDiv").append("<iframe></iframe>");
}
```

(but the first is better style anyway)