# How to check class name using javascript??

Tags: javascript

How to check class name using javascript?? 
I am using  this statement..  if (document.getElementByClass("expandable")

but it give me error..  "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: doubled question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422629/jquery-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-in-internet-explorer

Comment: if you want to check class name of some element -  document.getElementById('myid').className. What you are trying to do is get elements that have some class as it seems to me...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get All Elements in an HTML document with a specific CSS Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210377/get-all-elements-in-an-html-document-with-a-specific-css-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you just made that method up!

You want document.getElementsByClassName: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: Note that this method is relatively new, and thus not supported on older browsers.

Answer (score 2):

There is no function `document.getElementByClass`. Either check for the property `.className` of potential objects, or use a higher level framework which implements this (Such as [jquery](http://jquery.com/)). This is the syntax with jquery:

```
$(".expandable")
```

Answer (score 1):

Via pure javascript:
You can use the `getElementsByClassName` from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933602/how-to-getelementbyclass-instead-of-getelementbyid-with-javascript#answer-1933623)

With jQuery, this is lot more simple, use the [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/):

```
$(".className)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no function like `getElementByClass`.
2. You have to use `document.getElementsByClassName`; it will return an array
   so you have to use loop to get values.

But MSIE will not support this function so you have to check your class name like:

```
((document.getElementsByTagName("div"))[i].className)=="yourclassname"
```